# Python Script for printing contents on adjacent cell from a csv file based on matching criteria

Tags: python

I am new to python programming. I need to read contents from a csv file and print based on a matching criteria. The file contains columns like this:

abc, A, xyz, W
gfk, B, abc, Y, xyz, F

I want to print the contents of the adjacent column based on the matching input string. For e.g. if the string is abc it should print A, and W for xyz, and "no match" for gfk for the first row. This should be executed for each row until the end of the file.

I have the following code. However, don't know to select the adjacent column.

```
c= ['abc','xyz','gfk']
with open('filer.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    my_file = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in my_file:
        for i in c: 
            if i in row:
                print the contents of the adjacent cell
```

I would appreciate any help in completing this script.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach made it more difficult to print adjacent values, because even if you used `enumerate` to get the indices, you would have to search the row again, after finding each pattern (after `if i in row:` you wouldn't immediately know where it was in the row). By structuring the data in a dictionary it becomes simpler:

```
patterns = ['abc','xyz','gfk']
with open('filer.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh, skipinitialspace=True)
    for line in reader:
        print '---'
        content = dict(zip(line[::2], line[1::2]))
        for pattern in patterns:
            print "{}: {}".format(pattern, content.get(pattern, 'no match'))
```

`zip(line[::2], line[1::2])` creates a list of tuples from the adjacent elements of the list, which can be turned into a dictionary, where the patterns you are looking for are keys and the corresponding letters are values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the output I get is as follows. As you can see only the last tuple is matched.  ---
abc:  A
xyz: no match
gfk: no match
---
abc: no match
xyz: no match
gfk:  B

Comment: You have spaces in your file, you need to strip them if they are not meaningful.

Comment: Replace the third line with `reader = csv.reader(fh, skipinitialspace=True)`.

Comment: Is it possible to read the first element as a text and the second element of the dictionary as an integer from a csv file. For e.g.as  'A': 4, 'B':3, 'F':0 rather than 'A':'4', 'B':'3', 'F':'0'. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can replace `line[1::2]` with `map(int, line[1::2])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this for the CSV, but it basically do what you ask for

```
csv = [['abc', 'A', 'xyz', 'W'],
       ['gfk', 'B', 'abc', 'Y', 'xyz', 'F']]

match_string = ['abc','xyz','gfk']

for row in csv:
    for i, column_content in enumerate(row):
        if column_content in match_string:
            print row[i + 1]  # + 1 for the following column_content 'A', 'W', etc.
```

You should read about slicing : [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)